# My Visitor Visa for Canada is stuck at "is being processed at the Visa Office" for over a month now. What can I do?

Tags: visas, canada

I have been selected for a summer internship in Canada through the Mitacs Globalink Program. I had applied for a Visitor Visa on 15th March, 2018 at the VFS Office, New Delhi, India. I am an Indian Citizen. The average processing time for it is 18 days acccording to the IRCC website. We had applied in a group of five, out of which 2 of us are stuck. My departure is on 16th May, 2018 and I haven't heard anything from the Visa Office. I am going to the VFS Office to submit a request letter tomorrow. Any suggestions on what I can do to get my visa?